# Whether the function is surjective or not?

Tags: functions

How to check whether a function is surjective or not?
  function is $$f(x)=(x^{2}+1)^{35}$$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$
   How to write $F(x)$ in terms of $y$?

Comment: Isn't $(x^2+1)^{35}>0$?

Comment: So what value of $x$ gives $f(x)=0$?

Comment: Surjectivity is ill-defined without giving a co-domain

Comment: What do you mean with $F(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

If you consider it as a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, or even $f:\Bbb R\to[0,\infty)$, then it is not surjective. Indeed, $(x^2+1)^{35}\geq (0+1)^{35}=1^{35}=1$, so the range of $f$ is contained in $[1,\infty)$.

Actually, the range is precisely $[1,\infty)$, so the function
$$f:\Bbb R\to [1,\infty),\quad f(x)=(x^2+1)^{35}$$
is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

In general if $f:X\to Y$ is a function to be checked on surjectivity then find out the range of the function (i.e. the set $\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}\subseteq Y$). The function is surjective if and only if its range coincides with $Y$.

Alternatively you can wonder: can I find a function $g:Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g: Y\to Y$ is the identity on $Y$? The answer will be "yes" if and only if $f$ is surjective.

Your specific question can only be answered if $Y$ is known, wich is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

For this particular case, you can exhibit numbers which are not included in the image of $f$, 0 for instance :

$\forall x\in \mathbb R, (x^2+1)^{35}\geqslant 1$

so any $x<1$ is not attained by f. Hence f is not surjective.

Comment: How do you know that the range of $f$ contain a number inferior to $1$? As the OP didn't specify the co-domain, the function can or cannot be surjective

Comment: @Tryss without further knowledge I made the assumption that he asked whether this function was surjective on $\mathbb R$.
Any function is surjective on its image anyway.